# k8s can not schedule a pod because of one node didn't satisfy existing pods anti-affinity rules

Tags: kubernetes

I hava a k8s cluster with 3 nodes. When i  deploy a statefulset in this k8s cluster i found a question about K8S pod anti affinity rule.

This is the error message.

```
Warning  FailedScheduling  32s (x8 over 6m44s)  default-scheduler  0/3 nodes are available: 3 node(s) didn't match pod affinity/anti-affinity, 3 node(s) didn't satisfy existing pods anti-affinity rules.
```

This is the code about nodeAffinity and podAntiAffinity.

```
    spec:
      affinity:
        nodeAffinity:
          requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
            nodeSelectorTerms:
            - matchExpressions:
              - key: dolphin.region/name
                operator: In
                values:
                - common
        podAntiAffinity:
          requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
          - labelSelector:
              matchExpressions:
              - key: app.kubernetes.io/name
                operator: In
                values:
                - redis-sentinel
            topologyKey: kubernetes.io/hostname
```

The nodes info .

```
[root@k8s-10 ~]#  kubectl get nodes --show-labels
NAME              STATUS   ROLES    AGE   VERSION   LABELS
k8s-10.67.42.10   Ready    master   86d   v1.13.3   beta.kubernetes.io/arch=amd64,beta.kubernetes.io/os=linux,dolphin.region/name=common,k8s_ceph=ceph,kubernetes.io/hostname-master=kube-master,kubernetes.io/hostname=k8s-10.67.42.10,node-role.kubernetes.io/master=
k8s-10.67.42.11   Ready    master   86d   v1.13.3   beta.kubernetes.io/arch=amd64,beta.kubernetes.io/os=linux,dolphin.region/name=common,k8s_ceph=ceph,kubernetes.io/hostname-master=kube-master,kubernetes.io/hostname=k8s-10.67.42.11,node-role.kubernetes.io/master=
k8s-10.67.42.12   Ready    master   86d   v1.13.3   beta.kubernetes.io/arch=amd64,beta.kubernetes.io/os=linux,dolphin.region/name=common,k8s_ceph=ceph,kubernetes.io/hostname-master=kube-master,kubernetes.io/hostname=k8s-10.67.42.12,node-role.kubernetes.io/master=
```

There is only 3 pod have the label  app.kubernetes.io/name=redis-sentinel.

```
[root@k8s-10 ~]# kubectl get pod -n project -l app.kubernetes.io/name=redis-sentinel -o wide 
NAME                   READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE   IP              NODE              NOMINATED NODE   READINESS GATES
dol-redis-sentinel-0   1/1     Running   0          18h   10.244.243.2    k8s-10.67.42.12   <none>           <none>
dol-redis-sentinel-1   1/1     Running   0          16h   10.244.35.170   k8s-10.67.42.10   <none>           <none>
dol-redis-sentinel-2   0/1     Pending   0          29m   <none>          <none>            <none>           <none>
```

There is also no Taint in the node k8s-10.67.42.11

```
[root@k8s-10 ~]# kubectl describe node k8s-10.67.42.11 | grep Taint 
Taints:             <none>
```

```
[root@k8s-10 ~]# kubectl get pods --show-labels -n project |grep sentinel 
dol-redis-sentinel-0                              1/1     Running   0          18h     app.kubernetes.io/instance=dol-redis-sentinel,app.kubernetes.io/name=redis-sentinel,app=dol-redis-sentinel,controller-revision-hash=dol-redis-sentinel-b4975b6bd,statefulset.kubernetes.io/pod-name=dol-redis-sentinel-0
dol-redis-sentinel-1                              1/1     Running   0          16h     app.kubernetes.io/instance=dol-redis-sentinel,app.kubernetes.io/name=redis-sentinel,app=dol-redis-sentinel,controller-revision-hash=dol-redis-sentinel-b4975b6bd,statefulset.kubernetes.io/pod-name=dol-redis-sentinel-1
dol-redis-sentinel-2                              0/1     Pending   0          38m     app.kubernetes.io/instance=dol-redis-sentinel,app.kubernetes.io/name=redis-sentinel,app=dol-redis-sentinel,controller-revision-hash=dol-redis-sentinel-b4975b6bd,statefulset.kubernetes.io/pod-name=dol-redis-sentinel-2
dol-redis-sentinel-exporter-75c8cbdc97-wztpk      1/1     Running   0          7d      app.kubernetes.io/part-of=redis-sentinel,app=dol-redis-sentinel-exporter,dolphin/part-of-instance=dol-redis-sentinel,pod-template-hash=75c8cbdc97
```

The kubenetes server version is v1.13.3

```
[root@k8s-10 ~]# kubectl version
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"13", GitVersion:"v1.13.3", GitCommit:"721bfa751924da8d1680787490c54b9179b1fed0", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2019-02-01T20:08:12Z", GoVersion:"go1.11.5", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"13", GitVersion:"v1.13.3", GitCommit:"721bfa751924da8d1680787490c54b9179b1fed0", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2019-02-01T20:00:57Z", GoVersion:"go1.11.5", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
```

How can i  schedule  the pod  into the node k8s-10.67.42.11 .

Comment: Make sure node `k8s-10.67.42.11` has enough CPU/Memory for a new Pod.

Comment: podanitaffinity means new pods wont be scheduled if already such pods are running there , If I am correct you already have the pods with such labels which are mentioned in antiaffinity rule ,you need to modify the anitaffinity rule

Comment: @nobb, you are using very old, deprecated version of Kubernetes. Do you want to use the current one? Additionally, did the solution of confused genius work for you?

Answer (score 0):

I think its because there is node with label "app.kubernetes.io/name"

```
        podAntiAffinity:
          requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
          - labelSelector:
              matchExpressions:
              - key: app.kubernetes.io/name
                operator: In
                values:
                - redis-sentinel
[root@k8s-10 ~]# kubectl get pod -n project -l app.kubernetes.io/name=redis-sentinel -o wide 
NAME                   READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE   IP              NODE              NOMINATED NODE   READINESS GATES
dol-redis-sentinel-0   1/1     Running   0          18h   10.244.243.2    k8s-10.67.42.12   <none>           <none>
dol-redis-sentinel-1   1/1     Running   0          16h   10.244.35.170   k8s-10.67.42.10   <none>           <none>
dol-redis-sentinel-2   0/1     Pending   0          29m   <none>          <none>            <none>           <none>
```

- please set label "app.kubernetes.io/name=redis-sentinel" to nodes and check .

Comment: I try this but it  does not works. 
Three nodes have  the  same labels .

Comment: can you update the output of kubectl get nodes --show-labels after applying "app.kubernetes.io/name=redis-sentinel" to them ..